# JFrog CLI and Artifactory Cloud NPM repository

Tags: artifactory

When I run the npm install command with the JFrog CLI and my Artifactory Cloud installation, I get the following error

```
$ jfrog rt npm-install npm
[Info] Running npm Install.
[Error] This operation requires Artifactory version 5.5.2 or higher.
```

When I configured the CLI I do so with the URL i use to access artifactory cloud.

```
https://companyName.jfrog.io/companyName
```

I've checked the version of my cloud installation and its higher than the required version.

```
   artifactory.version  |  5.10.1
```

Note: I can access the NPM repository when using basic auth but require the jfrog CLI for the CI builds.

Can anyone shed some light? Has anyone else experienced this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the CLI NPM capabilities require Artifactory 5.5.2 and above, there is a validation mechanism of the version.
Due to a change in Artifactory, this validation currently fails, starting with Artifactory 5.10 and above.

This should be fixed within the next release of the JFrog CLI.
Thank you for the understanding.

Comment: Ok thank you. Do you know if there is a public jira ticket which can be tracked for this issue?

Comment: @AndyWooller I don't think there is.
You are for sure welcome to open one at: https://github.com/JFrogDev/jfrog-cli-go/commits/master

BTW i think the fix was already committed: https://github.com/JFrogDev/jfrog-cli-go/commit/ceca13567af8c7db1146ae576fcec3ab662fcc68

Comment: Hi @AndyWooller, a new JFrog CLI version has been released today (1.15.0), which include a fix for this issue. Download it from here: https://jfrog.com/getcli/